# Rails 3 - Trigger a task in the background in frequent intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background

I need to schedule a task that needs to run on a particular interval.

What are the gems / plugins available in rails 3 for achieving the same? If we have a list, how should we choose one among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever is by far the most popular gem for using cron to do this.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Thanks, I heard of this gem, but never tried. Will give a try this time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure a gem is needed at all for this, cron was built for exactly this purpose, why not leverage it?

This seems to be a good solution:

[Rails3, Running rake task from cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518499/rails3-running-rake-task-from-cron)

The gist: convert the job into a rake task, which you can run with an environment variable.

Comment: Good suggestion, I have tried this before. My idea was to know the other possible solutions and do it in the best possible way.